# Python TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, string, csv, buffer

I have the below code that was working fine and then started throwing this error. I have a csv file that I am trying to write one row to. While other solutions involve converting things to a byte string first, since I'm working with a csv, I'm not sure I can do that.

**Code:**

```
def saveFile():
    with open('data.csv','wb') as out:
        csv_out=csv.writer(out)
        csv_out.writerow(['Domain:','Mail Server:','TLS:','# of Employees:','Verified:'])
        for row in root.pt.get_rows():
            #csv_out.writerow(row)
            print (row)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/kylec/Desktop/DataMotion/Python/MailChecker.py", line 93, in saveFile
    csv_out.writerow(['Domain:','Mail Server:','TLS:','# of Employees:','Verified:'])
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, the `csv` module expects you to give it a file in *text mode*:

```
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as out:
```

The `newline=''` argument gives the `csv` module control over how newlines are written (the reason why in Python 2 you opened the file in binary mode).

From the [`csv.writer()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

> If *csvfile* is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''`.
>
> [...]
>
> If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use `\r\n` linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added. It should always be safe to specify `newline=''`, since the csv module does its own (*universal*) newline handling.

Because you gave the module a binary-mode file, you can only write *`bytes` data* to it.

Comment: Just so I know, isn't that what wb is for?

Comment: @Kyle: in *Python 2* you'd have to open the file in binary mode, yes. But this isn't Python 2.