# Combine text files into key/value

Tags: python, excel

I'm using a macro in Excel to create a key/value pair as follows:

```
Sub GetKeyValue()
    Dim FileName As String, i As Integer, str As String

    FileName = "C:\keyvalue.txt"

    Open FileName For Output As #1

    For i = 1 To 50
        str = Cells(i, 1) & ", " & Cells(i, 2)
        Print #1, str
    Next i
    Close #1
End Sub
```

The above takes the values in A1-A50 and B1-B50 and uses them as a basis for creating the file.

**How could I do something similar in Python?**

My thinking is having two text files, one for the keys and one for the values, and merging the two and then storing it in a dictionary object.

Comment: not getting? you means one file contains key A1, A2, ... A50, B1, ....B50 an other text file contains respective values and then Create xls file from that ?

Comment: Yes, however, it doesn't have to be xls. It can be a text file with the merged key/value pairs. The important thing is this gets stored in a dictionary as this will be used to compare two or more dictionaries later on.

Comment: Can it be read as a csv separated by commas?

Comment: Assume Text1.txt has all the Keys, Assume Text2.txt has all the values, a file should be created Merged.txt that has the key and values together separated by commas. From there, take Merged.txt and store the key/value pairs in a dictionary.

Comment: @Daniel Jimenez: Yes, it may stored as a csv. Whatever is easier.

Comment: @Brian in your example you have the keys in A and the values in B but from one file. Also are the files the same length? and Do the files have more cells than the values and keys cells?

Comment: That's because I wasn't sure how to merge the two across two separate sheets. It's just easier to look at side by side if they're in neighboring cells.
@Daniel: EDIT: No, it's a simple pairing of CAS Chemical identifiers to the chemical names. The chemical names (the values) vary in length.

Comment: Can you include a sample of how the files look like and what is the expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the csv module assuming the values and keys come from cell A and B of the same file.

```
import csv
with open("file.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    d = {line[0]:line[1] for line in reader}
```

If the keys and values come from different files you can store the pairs in a dictionary as:

```
with open("keys.csv", "r") as the_keys, open("values.csv", "r") as the_values:
keys = csv.reader(the_keys)
values = csv.reader(the_values)
my_dic = {line1[0]:line2[0] for line1,line2 in zip(keys,values)} 

# Write to a new csv file.    
with open("final.csv", "wb") as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=',')
    for k,v in my_dic.iteritems():
        writer.writerow([k,v])
```

You can skip the csv module and just write the files as:

```
with open("keys.txt", "r") as f, open("values.txt", "r") as x:
    h = {line1.strip():line2.strip() for line1,line2 in zip(f,x)}

with open("final.csv", "w") as out:
    for k,v in h.iteritems():
        out.write("{},{}\n".format(k,v))
```

Comment: Great, however, I wanted to avoid going through Excel. Is there any way to generate a CSV from text files using the CSV module?

Comment: Yes it's  possible and easy as well. If you post  a sample of the files i can show you how to do it.

Comment: [Keys Text File][1]


  [1]: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8f4dyuq1qs620re/keys.txt?dl=0

[Values Text File][2]

  [2]: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7f4epg0zmbnwxrr/values.txt?dl=0

Comment: As you can see both text files do not have commas which makes it more difficult to concatenate the files. The intention is to have a script that prompts the user to populate the text file and have some python magic add commas where they need to go and format it as a csv.

Comment: would these be an ok match  `104-76-7:2-Ethyl-Hexanol` `00064-19-7:Acetic Acid 56%` `64-19-7:Acetic Acid Glacial` etc

Comment: I noticed that you have repetitive keys and also have and empty key in your key.txt that will cause a problem.

Comment: yes, because in Dictionary key are unique. We can create counter as key and value is list of key and value . e.g. `{1:["104-76-7", "2-Ethyl-Hexanol"], 2:["00064-19-7", "Acetic Acid 56%"]}`

Comment: Or use a `defaultdict` and have the values as list members

Comment: @Daniel: The above code uses Python 2.7. Anything for 3? I get a 'str' does not support the buffer interface error.

Comment: @Brian this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294457/python-typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface

Comment: @Daniel, thanks that helped, however, the code only retrieves one line and stores it in the dictionary. Not quite sure why.

Comment: Not quite sure why. In python 2 works just fine. if its only one line, maybe it will be better just to read it without the csv module